# laravel services using model and services

Tags: laravel, service, model, using

I am trying to cut my code correctly and I would like your opinion on a point. Can I call a service in another service?

I find simple examples on the internet

Here is my architecture :

```
UserController
    UserService
        User
            Fields => id, name

AliasController
    AliasService
        Alias
            Fields => id, user_id, name
```

1 user have many alias
If no alias is defined, it is generated

form

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="alias">
```

UserController

```
public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();

    $this->userService->create(request()->except(['_token']));

    return back()->with('success', 'created');
}
```

UserService

```
class UserService
{
    protected $user;
    protected $alias;

    public function __construct(User $user, AliasService $aliasService)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->alias = $alias;
    }

    public function create(array $attributes)
    {
        // create user
        $user = $this->user->create($attributes);

        // create or generate alias
        if (isset($attributes['alias'])) {
            $aliasName = $attributes['alias'];
        } else {
            $aliasName = $this->aliasService->generate($user->name);
        }

        $this->aliasService->create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'alias' => $aliasName
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

EDIT 18/02/2019:

I have a question: if I have to use a single service in my controller, how do I get the list of roles in the create method?

class UserController extends Controller
    {
        protected $userService;

```
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $user = new User();

        $roles = Role::all(); <= ???
        or
        $roles = $this->roleService->getAll(); <= ???

        return view('users.create', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'roles' => $roles
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use a service into an other service but it is "forbidden" to use two differents services in a controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Why it's forbidden to have 2 services in the same controller ?

Comment: It's a good practice. The good way is to have 1 Controller and this Controller call his Service. And it's in the Service that the logic, the "operations" take place. It's for this reason than you normally have to use in the Controller only his Service. And this service make operations and if it needs other services it calls them. ( sorry my english is not very nice ^^ )

Comment: pas grave j'ai compris ;)
thank you I continue like that

Comment: I have another question, can I use other model in the service?

Comment: Haha :p Yes you can use an other model in your service.

Answer (score 0):

I feel when  you want to separate a logic which is involves models create-update functions, you can use `Repository` concept. Essentially nothing but a class which takes care of actions happening on a particular model.

A service is more like a class which is dedicated to a particular domain concept. The purpose of a service to provide helper functions to deal with the domain concept  that service represents.

To simplify, for example:

You may have a user model. Each user can fetch his facebookfeeds. Also he can enrol to a group discussion. In this case you can have 2 services :

`FacebookService` which takes care of all actions you will need related to facebook posting. 
`DiscussionService` which takes care of all actions you will need related to group discussions.

Now, you might want to add a functionality in a discussion to post a recent discussion on facebook. Which means that  `DiscussionService` can internally access `FacebookService` to utilise it's certain  helper functions.

Even if in this example, the 2 services are used together, still each service is only doing what it knows as per the domain concept it is assigned to. If something out of the scope of service comes up, we call the respective service function. Hope that helps...

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I did not make repositories because in a repositories, it is necessary to use only a model. I prefer to use Eloquent directly.
I do not need this layer because I use a single database

Comment: Its okay to not use repositories. But I hope my answer helped you to understand that two services can be called within each other :)